# Theorem regarding the derivative of an inverse function

Tags: calculus

I'm quoting a well know theorem:

> Given an invertible function $f : U → V$, with $U \subseteq ℝ$ neighborhood of a point $p$, if $f'(p)$ exists non zero and $f^{-1}$ is continuous in $f(p)$, then $[f^{-1}]'(f(p)) = 1/f'(p)$.

Of this I only have a sketch of a proof that starts by assuming that $f(p)$ is an internal point of $V$ (or at least a limit point, because limits are freely evaluated), but this isn't proved. I'm looking for the proof that the assumption made is legit. Thanks.

Comment: The tricky part is showing that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable; this is not obvious to me just from continuity of $f^{-1}$ and existence of $f'$.